# excel: is it possible to put a FOR statement as a formula within a cell?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

can i do this `=(For i=1 to 100, print i)`

is there a way to put a FOR statement inside a cell WITHOUT USING VBA?

Comment: May I ask why there is a no-VBA restriction? I don't know of a way to do this kind of thing without VBA.

Comment: @adam shana tova, no VBA because i dont want to be too fancy

Comment: @downvoter: it's generally helpful to provide a reason for your dissatisfaction with an answer.

Comment: yes and an explanation why you didnt like my question

Comment: @adam are you there my frrrrrrend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VBA for this isn't fancy at all :-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SimpleForLoop()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100 Step 1
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
            .Value = .Value + i
        End With        
    Next
End Sub
```

The simple code above puts the value 5050 in cell A1.

If you want to concatenate a string instead, slap this code into your for-loop:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = CStr(i)
        Else
            .Value = .Value & "," & CStr(i)
        End If
    End With
```

Which will print the following into cell A2:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to get the numbers 1 through 100, but you're limited on what you can do with them.  You can't, for instance, concatenate in an array formula (which your pseudo code suggests).  But you could SUM, AVERAGE or many other operations.

```
{=SUM(ROW(1:100))}
{=AVERAGE(ROW(1:100))}
{=MAX(ROW(1:100))}
```

The braces means enter with control+shift+enter, not just enter.